# Spinner not changing when value is clicked

Tags: java, android

I am working on an app within Android Studio.  I have a simple spinner on one of my fragments.  I load it with data from an arraylist like so

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_main, container, false);

    Spinner ddlLocation = (Spinner) myView.findViewById(R.id.ddlLocation);
    //ddlLocation.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    //Load the nameList array into the drop down list (Spinner)
    LocationDBHandler locationDBHandler = new LocationDBHandler(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),null,null,1);
    ArrayList<String> nameList = locationDBHandler.getAllNames();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, nameList);
    ddlLocation.setPrompt("Select a Location");
    ddlLocation.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    return myView;
}
```

When I run the app, I can click on the arrow beside the spinner and I see my arraylist of items, great.  When I click on an item it does not change what is displayed int the Spinner (it's not my text color).  Also, I get null pointer errors when trying to access what is in the Spinner.

Logcat after navigating a page and selecting an item from the dropdown.

```
01-07 21:42:43.754 20554-20567/? W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-07 21:42:43.754 20554-20567/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xaee534c0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
01-07 21:42:54.747 20554-20567/com.example.connor.connorminstafeed W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-07 21:42:54.747 20554-20567/com.example.connor.connorminstafeed W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xab6abd00, error=EGL_SUCCESS
01-07 21:42:56.464 20554-20567/com.example.connor.connorminstafeed E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xab0f6b20
```

Null Pointer

```
01-07 21:49:15.463 22000-22000/com.example.connor.connorminstafeed E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                 Process: com.example.connor.connorminstafeed, PID: 22000
                                                                                 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.widget.Spinner.getSelectedItem()' on a null object reference
                                                                                     at com.example.connor.connorminstafeed.HistoryFragment.onCreateView(HistoryFragment.java:38)
                                                                                     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2220)
                                                                                     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:973)
                                                                                     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1148)
                                                                                     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:793)
                                                                                     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1535)
                                                                                     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:482)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Array List Code.  Wouldnt think this would be the issue since the Spinner is populating fine?

```
public ArrayList<String> getAllNames() {
    String query = "SELECT name FROM " + TABLE_LOCATION;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

    ArrayList<String> nameList = new ArrayList<String>();

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
            nameList.add(name);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    return nameList;
}
```

Spinner XML

```
    <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/ddlLocation"
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="83dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:textColor="#475afd"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView11" />
```

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you please post the logs?

Comment: Sorry, I'm pretty new to this.  Do you mean the logs in the Logcat window?  I'll add those to the question anyway.

Comment: Yes. Thank you. Please add the NPE logs or the logs right after you select.

Comment: Added the NPE log after navigating to a page that pulls information from that spinner.

Comment: Can you please post your adapter code? It looks like something is misconfigured in your adapter.

Comment: Do you mean the code that generates the Array List that is used in the adapter? I've posted that

Comment: Can you post your spinner code?

Comment: The XML? I dont't have anything else I dont think.  Sorry, just started with Java and Android yesterday.

Comment: in onItemSelected method what are u trying to do?

Comment: I haven't set it to do anything yet.  I just want to be able to select a value with the Spinner, then access that value from other fragments.  Except it always returns null.  I can see the items, but when I click on them they do not display and I do not think they are being selected.  Thanks.

Comment: try the below solution it sholud work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make you nameList global.and write the code in onitemselected like below and check selected item is coming or not.if yes then proceed further.

```
 @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

        Toast.makeText(this,""+nameList.get(i),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

and in your xml change background color of spinner.like below

android:background="#676767"

```
<Spinner
    android:background="#676767"
    android:id="@+id/ddlLocation"
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="83dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:textColor="#475afd"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView11" />
```